# Is it possible to take a screenshot of the whole page with Selenium/Capybara?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, screenshot

PhantomJS has the option of taking a screenshot of the whole page (not just the current viewport). Is there any way to do so using Selenium? I am running the Cucumber/Capybara tests headlessly, using the headless gem. I would use PhantomJS, but I've had some other problems with it.

Comment: Capybara has a method for it - http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#save_screenshot-instance_method. It's supported by Selenium too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I've been using the `take_screenshot` method that was provided by the headless gem, when I could have just used the `page.save_screenshot()` method, which does exactly what I need. Thank you, Andrey.

Answer (score 57):

In case anyone washed up this shore looking for how to do this with **Poltergeist** you just need to pass the `full` argument:

```
page.save_screenshot('screen.png', full: true) # If providing a custom file name.
page.save_screenshot(full: true)               # Capybara sets a name based on timestamp.
page.save_and_open_screenshot('screen.png', full: true) # Same as save_screenshot.
page.save_and_open_screenshot(full: true)               # Same as save_screenshot.
```

[Docs](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I chose to use `puts save_screenshot(nil, full: true)` so it generated a random filename and printed it out.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot of things to get full height working with Capybara/Selenium.

Only one thing I tried seemed to work, and it was using headless_chrome. Bear in mind that I use a loop to take screenshots at different widths:

```
  def screenshot
    driver = Capybara.current_session.driver
    window = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window
    widths = [320, 1380] #leave normal w as last
    widths.each do |w|
      window.resize_to(w, 900)
      total_width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth")
      total_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      window.resize_to(total_width, total_height)
      save_screenshot
    end
  end
```

I resize it twice to get the height info.

rails_helper.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { 
      "args" => %w{ 
        headless 
        disable-gpu
        --disable-notifications
      } 
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

Capybara.javascript_driver     = :headless_chrome
Capybara.current_driver        = :headless_chrome
```

Comment: What file would you be putting the `def screenshot` method in? Just a spec helper file?

Comment: @littleforest any file that's required into your `spec/rails_helper.rb`. So yeah a helper would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
After do |scenario|
  take_screenshot(@browser, scenario)
end

def take_screenshot(browser, scenario)
  if scenario.failed?
    scenario_name = scenario.name.gsub /[^\w\-]/, ' '
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M")
    screenshot_path = './failed_png/' + time + ' - ' + scenario_name + '.png'
  else
    scenario_name = scenario.name.gsub /[^\w\-]/, ' '
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M")
    screenshot_path = './success_png/' + time + ' - ' + scenario_name + '.png'
  end
  browser.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
end
```

If you make a failed_png and success_png folder, this code will take a screenshot for each success and failure, and put it in the respective folders with the timestamp on it.  This code goes in your env.rb file, and makes it so you do not have to use any helpers or add any extra code to your step defs.

Comment: Thanks, Whitney. I already have automated screenshots in place, but only in case of failure. I also output the html at the moment of failure for debugging purposes. I use something like `File.open("errors/#{filename}.html", 'w') {|f| f.write(page.html)}`